# Best way to re-use modules/themes across multiple repositories

Tags: versioning

We run 3 websites. We have the same core module on our three websites. We also have a core theme that each of the three webites' theme uses as the parent.

Right now if I make an edit to the `Vendor_Core` module or `frontend/vendor/default` theme then I will manually copy the files across to the other 2 websites which isn't ideal.

What's the best way to manage this? I have three separate repositories for the whole Magento project..

should I move the core module and theme into their own repos?

Comment: Here you have 2 options.
1. Move the core module and theme into their own repos.
2. Create child theme for the particular websites.